# Can't install traits on windows, python

Tags: python, traits, traitsui

**Windows 10 64bit**

I installed traitsui successfully by pip in python3.52

Qt4 must be installed to display GUI on windows, But the highest version of python Qt4 support is python3.4

So, I install python3.4, when I try to install traits by pip

I got error message:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)
```

[image: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat]

I search the error message, get some results, But none of them solve the problem, So I install **mingw**

use pip to install traits again, get another error

```
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'D:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-5.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

[image: collect2.exe: error]

Is there a way to install traits on windows in python 3.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can circumvent the problem of the error with Visual Studio C++ by installing a precompiled version of the package in form of a `wheel`. You can find `wheel` packages for most of the common modules [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Download the file `traits-4.6.0.dev0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl` (`cp34` indicates Python 3.4, `win32` that your Python is 32bit) and install it using the command line:

```
pip install C:\whereveryourfileis\traits-4.6.0.dev0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl
```

Make sure that `pip` is linked to your Python 3.4 pip. If you are unsure, you can run the `pip.exe` directly by changing your directory in the command line (`cd C:\Python34\Scripts`) and running

```
pip.exe install C:\whereveryourfileis\traits-4.6.0.dev0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl
```

Edit: Did you consider using `Qt5`?

Comment: Thank you very much. I reinstall the 32 bit python version and use the wheel packages, It finally works. Of course I want to use Qt5, but I don't think traitsUI support Qt5. And sorry to bother you again, I use 'pyinstaller' to pack the first example of [traitsui_doc](https://docs.enthought.com/traitsui/traitsui_user_manual/view.html) and get [error_messege](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S1oXu.png) But works well when I type 'python t.py' in command line, I wonder if I can pack the traitsUI example to exe file on windows?

Comment: Glad I could be of help. On your second matter I advise you to open another question. I am afraid I can't help you with `pyinstaller` problems.

Comment: doesn't work for me :\ ... says "ERROR: traits-6.1.1-cp39-cp39-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform." tried the one for 64, didn't work either

Comment: @Raksha What platform (Win 32/64?) and python version are you using? Do you maybe have another python installation and pip is actually coming from that? Navigate to your python folder and execute pip.exe directly from the command line.